# Greenplum reports "got an out of order request, sequence number is A, expected sequence number is B"

Tags: greenplum

When initial request was sent with sequence num 1, I sent post request with data and sequence num 2.

Gpfdist return response with status 400 (invalid request due to wrong sequence number) to this request.

In logs it wrote:

> got an out of order request, sequence number is 2, expected sequence number is 3904674963453378562.

Why expected number is `3904674963453378562` and not `2`? What I should do with this problem?

Comment: Please add a code example.  I don't know why you would send a post to gpfdist either.